# Simulate access on different country

Tags: performance, testing, networking

Is it possible to simulate the access from different country, say, the server is in US, and I want to test my application's performance from Taiwan, Japan or Malaysia, and my pc is in Hong Kong.

How can I do that? I try use TOR(maybe I'm going wrong, please correct me), but it looks like can't manually connect with different router, and seems the data is transfer like this

my pc->Tor network->web server->Tor network->my pc

however, what I suppose to test is like this

my pc-(vnc)->remote pc<->web server

Please give me some direction, thanks, a lot~!

Comment: What aspects do you want to test? Bandwidth? Latency? How your application behaves behind the great (fire)wall of China? Test that your location service on your site works OK?

Comment: because it is a facebook apps, and I decided to rent a host which located at US, however, the application is for chinese reader, therefore, I want to test is the network speed fast enough for the user, or whatelse I can discover during the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rent a VPS for a month, in the country you want to test with.

Or pay someone on rentacoder.com or mturk.com or craigslist.org from those countries to submit test results data to you.

Comment: Thanks very much servermanfail, because I plan the apps will have difference language version(for diff. country), therefore, US server is first choice for me, last night I do some homework, and found that the server located at west coast is seems ok for ASIA user(ping 200ms), what is your opinion?